# How do I solve Gnosis error code GS020 when I attempt to create a Contract Interaction within Gnosis?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

Every time I try to create a contract interaction on Gnosis it displays this transaction will most likely fail. I update the gas fees to try and submit but it fails with...

Confirmation transaction failed - Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

```js
// Check that the provided signature data is not too short
        require(signatures.length >= requiredSignatures.mul(65), "GS020");
        // There cannot be an owner with address 0.
        address lastOwner = address(0);
        address currentOwner;
        uint8 v;
        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint256 i;
        for (i = 0; i < requiredSignatures; i++) {
            (v, r, s) = signatureSplit(signatures, i);
            if (v == 0) {
```

There is no option within Gnosis to update the signatures. Could anyone help please?

Comment: How do you create the transaction? Please add more info

Comment: It might not be your end. Having same issues with my vault! Not cool!